Python merge or concat multiple dfs with intersecting datetime index
Using Pandas can you merge multiple dataframes with a timestamp column and common columns (in this case) station, longitude, latitude and a multiple variable columns in separate files But not duplicate the common columns, or have multiple rows for the time column in the end result?
Examples of first input file:
time,station,latitude[unit="degrees_north"],longitude[unit="degrees_east"],ta50m[unit="K"]
2023-01-01T00:00:00Z,GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E],-23.540,133.360,300.1109619140625
2023-01-01T01:00:00Z,GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E],-23.540,133.360,301.6109619140625
2023-01-01T02:00:00Z,GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E],-23.540,133.360,303.60748291015625

Examples of second input file:
time,station,latitude[unit="degrees_north"],longitude[unit="degrees_east"],ua50m[unit="m s-1"]
2023-01-01T00:00:00Z,GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E],-23.540,133.360,-3.38525390625
2023-01-01T01:00:00Z,GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E],-23.540,133.360,-5.17431640625
2023-01-01T02:00:00Z,GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E],-23.540,133.360,-7.213134765625

Third+ input file:
time,station,latitude[unit="degrees_north"],longitude[unit="degrees_east"],ua50m[unit="m s-1"]
2023-02-01T00:00:00Z,GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E],-23.540,133.360,-2.19775390625
2023-02-01T01:00:00Z,GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E],-23.540,133.360,-1.4140625
2023-02-01T02:00:00Z,GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E],-23.540,133.360,-0.692626953125

(Desired) Target file:
time,station,"latitude[unit=""degrees_north""]","longitude[unit=""degrees_east""]","ta50m[unit=""K""]","ua50m[unit=""m s-1""]"
2023-01-01T00:00:00Z,GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E],-23.54,133.36,300.1109619140625,-3.38525390625
2023-01-01T01:00:00Z,GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E],-23.54,133.36,301.6109619140625,-5.17431640625
2023-01-01T02:00:00Z,GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E],-23.54,133.36,303.60748291015625,-7.213134765625
...
2023-02-01T00:00:00Z,GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E],-23.54,133.36,292.739501953125,-2.19775390625
2023-02-01T01:00:00Z,GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E],-23.54,133.36,293.239501953125,-1.4140625

pd.merge (and merge_ordered, and merge_asof) doesn't seem to work properly with a multi-column index or it returns duplicate suffixed columns for station, latitude and longitude.
time,station,"latitude[unit=""degrees_north""]","longitude[unit=""degrees_east""]","ta50m[unit=""K""]","ua50m[unit=""m s-1""]_x","ua50m[unit=""m s-1""]_y"
2023-01-01T00:00:00Z,GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E],-23.54,133.36,300.1109619140625,-3.38525390625,NULL
2023-01-01T01:00:00Z,GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E],-23.54,133.36,301.6109619140625,-5.17431640625,NULL

Converting the time column to a datetime index and using pd.concat seems to be the right way to go...but then how do you fix for separate time rows and get rid of the NaN values? I thought groupby on the index might be a way to go, but how?

Images of data/code are not acceptable. Please provide a [mre] that will allow us to reproduce your issue.

Updated the original post.
Noting the issue I was getting was with an 'outer' merge on the dataframes. After more trials and a possible solution (which i've added below) it makes sense that it doesn't dynamically merge the new dataframe column with the same name, rather it suffixes it, so as not to overwrite values.

Without a sample of code, it can be hard to reproduce your problem. I have handcrafted two DataFrames to replicate your data.
index_common = [
    datetime(2023,1,1,0,0,0,0).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'),
    datetime(2023,1,1,1,0,0,0).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'),
    datetime(2023,1,1,2,0,0,0).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
]
data_1 = {
    'station': ['GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E]']*3, 
    'longitude': [-23.53]*3,
    'latitude': [133.36]*3,
    'ta50m': [300.11, 301.61, 303.60]
}
data_2 = {
    'station': ['GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E]']*3, 
    'longitude': [-23.53]*3,
    'latitude': [133.36]*3,
    'ua50m': [-3.38, -5.17, -7.21]
}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data_1, index=index_common)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data_2, index=index_common)

When having a look at them, they share a common timestamp index.
In [1]: df1
Out[1]:
                                                     station longitude latitude ta50m
2023-01-01T00:00:00Z    GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E]  -23.53  133.36  300.11
2023-01-01T01:00:00Z    GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E]  -23.53  133.36  301.61
2023-01-01T02:00:00Z    GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E]  -23.53  133.36  303.60

In [2]: df2
Out[2]: 
                                                      station longitude latitude ua50m
2023-01-01T00:00:00Z    GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E]  -23.53  133.36  -3.38
2023-01-01T01:00:00Z    GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E]  -23.53  133.36  -5.17
2023-01-01T02:00:00Z    GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E]  -23.53  133.36  -7.21

The idea here is to reset the index of both DataFrames and use the pd.merge function to merge the DataFrames over the ex-timestamp index and the common columns:
df_merged = df_1.reset_index(names=['timestamp']).merge(
    df_2.reset_index(names=['timestamp']), 
    how='inner', 
    on=['timestamp', 'station', 'longitude', 'latitude']
)

Finally, if you need to let the timestamp as an index and not as a proper column, you can run:
df_merged.set_index("timestamp")

In [3]: df_merged
Out[3]:
                                                     station  longitude latitude ta50m ua50m
timestamp                   
2023-01-01T00:00:00Z    GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E]  -23.53  133.36  300.11  -3.38
2023-01-01T01:00:00Z    GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E]  -23.53  133.36  301.61  -5.17
2023-01-01T02:00:00Z    GridPointRequestedAt[23.553S_133.396E]  -23.53  133.36  303.60  -7.21

PS: To easily share a sample of your data, you can run df.head().to_dict() and share the output here.

After spending a bit more time on the 'outer' dataframe merges (joins) approach, I came up with this solution which calls a function to combine the suffixed columns each time a csv file is merged, using the pandas.DataFrame.combine_first method.
def merge_csvs_to_df(filein_folder: str,
                filename_pattern: str = '*.csv',
                index_for_join: str = None) -> pd.DataFrame:
"""
Function to merge csv files iteratively from a folder based on filename wildcard.
If filename wildcard is omitted all csv files in the folder will be merged.

Args:
    filein_folder (str): Optional
    filename_pattern (str):
    index_for_join (str):

Returns:
    DataFrame: A DataFrame with the merged csvs.

Todo:
    add .csv check for filename_prefix
"""

def merge_suffix_columns(df: pd.DataFrame, suffix_x: str = '_x', suffix_y: str = '_y') -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Function to merge DataFrame columns with '_x' and '_y' suffixes.

    Args:
        df: The DataFrame that contains columns with suffixes to be merged.
        suffix_x: The suffix used in the first set of columns (default is '_x').
        suffix_y: The suffix used in the second set of columns (default is '_y').

    Returns:
        DataFrame: A DataFrame with the merged columns.
        If no suffix_x returns the original DataFrame.

    Todo:
        Add checks for multiple and mismatched suffixed columns
    """
    for column in df.columns:
        if column.endswith(suffix_x):
            base_column = column[:-len(suffix_x)]
            column_y = base_column + suffix_y
            if column_y in df.columns:
                # Create a new column without suffix and merge the values
                df[base_column] = df[column].combine_first(df[column_y])
                # Drop the old suffix columns
                df.drop([column, column_y], axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df

# initiate dataframe for combined csv results
df_combined = pd.DataFrame()

for file in Path(filein_folder).glob(filename_pattern):
    print(f"Merging file: {file}")
    if df_combined.empty:
        # read csv file without indexing to retain time as column for join
        df_combined = pd.read_csv(file)
    else:
        # read next file into new df
        df_add = pd.read_csv(file)
        # combine on index join if not None, otherwise just concat together
        # todo df_combined = df1.merge(df2,how='outer') seems to guess the matching columns
        df_combined = pd.merge(df_combined, df_add, how='outer', on=index_for_join)
        df_combined = merge_suffix_columns(df_combined)

return df_combined

